# Does lazy minting cost less gas than minting and transfering an NFT?

Tags: erc-721, nft

For traditional NFT minting, the artist will mint the NFT, and then later transfer it to the first buyer.

Does lazy minting save gas by not needing to transfer the NFT from the artist to the first buyer?

Comment: There are some markets that do not mint an NFT until someone buys them. Probably they do that to save some gas, how much? it depends on the implementation and NFT volume.

Comment: How does NFT volume affect it? I would have thought that gas prices would be similar, since you have to pay the same amount to alter (or create) each entry

Comment: Gas calculation is quite complex, so it is not easy to say that something will be cheaper or not. The best thing you can do is implement a solution and measure the gas usage.